# Slow Load Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datatables

For this particular use case I have a method that gets all the sales opportunities for a user, for the inventory he has in stock. It's a loop that goes through the user's parts and then checks each part against the "reverse-auction" to make sure the auction is an opportunity and if it is, stick it in this array 'sales_opportunities'

So, in my `Auction` model I have the method:

```
  def self.get_sales_opportunities(user)
    parts = user.inventory_parts
    parts.uniq! { |part| [part[:part_num], part[:condition]] }

    sales_opportunities = []
    parts.each do |part|
      #stick auction in sales opportunities
      #if the auction is not the user's, already contains a user bid,
      #or if the auction isn't asking for the part in-question's condition
      Auction.where(part_num: part.part_num, active: true).each do |auction|
        user_created_auction = (auction.company == user)
        user_has_placed_bids = (auction.bids & user.bids).present?
        part_matches = auction.condition.include?(part.condition)
        all_conditions = true if auction.condition[0].blank?

        sales_opportunities << auction unless user_created_auction || user_has_placed_bids || !part_matches
        sales_opportunities << auction if all_conditions && auction.company != user && !user_has_placed_bids
      end
    end
    sales_opportunities.uniq
  end
```

This is obviously a process and the load time is terrible..

How can I do this more efficiently?

Comment: you can create a normal table (populate with a loop) and define the HTML table like datatable (you can search, order, ...)

Comment: That is what I was doing, and it was taking very long for the view to load

Comment: Then your problem is not datatable is your code

Comment: As I stated in my question

Comment: but your question title say other